# SQL Query Yield Distinct by one column

Tags: sql

I know there are some other topics similar to what I am trying to accomplish but I'm struggling on this. I need to be able to get distinct SQL query results for one column but not the other using a fairly complex query from multiple tables.

This is the current query:

```
select llattrdata.ID dataid,

max(case when llattrdata.ATTRID = 2 then llattrdata.VALSTR end) TED_ID

from llattrdata, dtree 

where
llattrdata.DEFID = 19400074 and
llattrdata.VERNUM = dtree.VERSIONNUM and
llattrdata.ID = dtree.DATAID

group by llattrdata.ID
```

Current Results:
DATAID   TED_ID
19400078   10083
19400943   10083
19400941   10335

Desired Results:
DATAID   TED_ID
 19400078   10083
 19400941   10335

Can anybody help me out? I know it probably involves some sort of join but am not entirely sure how to proceed in this instance.

Comment: Why is the first row "19400078 10083" and not "19400943 10083"?

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(dataid) dataid, TED_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT
        llattrdata.ID dataid,
        MAX(CASE WHEN llattrdata.ATTRID = 2 THEN llattrdata.VALSTR END) TED_ID
    FROM llattrdata
    JOIN dtree ON llattrdata.ID = dtree.DATAID
    WHERE llattrdata.DEFID = 19400074
    AND llattrdata.VERNUM = dtree.VERSIONNUM
    GROUP BY llattrdata.ID
) T1
GROUP BY TED_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the MAX() function to the first SELECT item instead of the second.

Answer (score 0):

You could try grouping by the second column and using min() or max() on the first, given that you don't mind which value is chosen for the first.  Although I'm not sure if you can nest group functions like this- depends on the db (you could with a view or similar)